# GROUP BY with ORDER BY / last post_time

Tags: sql, group-by, mariadb

I have a list of writers in a topic. The List shows the writers name a the last post time inside this topic.

A member can also write more frequently in the topic. Therefore a "group by" was set on the poster_id.

The whole list should be sorted according to the write date. The newest comes first. So I placed maxtime DESC.

Problem:

The list output is working very well but the date of a writer's last post is not the last post_time but always the first post_time.

Table "**USERS**":

| user_id | username |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Marc |
| 2 | Paul |
| 3 | Sofie |
| 4 | Julia |

Table "**POSTS**"

| post_id | topic_id | poster_id | post_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4565 | 6 | 1 | 999092051 |
| 4567 | 6 | 4 | 999094056 |
| 4333 | 6 | 2 | 999098058 |
| 7644 | 6 | 1 | 999090055 |

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
    p.poster_id, 
    p.post_time, 
    p.post_id,   
    Max(p.post_time) AS maxtime, 
    u.user_id, 
    u.username,
FROM POSTS as p 
INNER JOIN USERS as u ON u.user_id = p.poster_id 
WHERE p.topic_id = 6 
GROUP BY p.poster_id 
ORDER BY maxtime DESC
```

How is it possible to display the last post_time of the poster_id instead the first one.

Comment: post_time is int(11). I think I need a 2nd query inside of the query to get the latest post_time of the poster_id but I dont know how to connect this.

Comment: Show the last post_time instead of the first post_time in each row for every single poster_id. Do you understand? Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using columns in `Select` which are not in group by or in an aggregation function is in most db's forbiden, becuase it is not defined which values are shown.

You can use a subquery with `group by` and `having`

```
SELECT 
    p.poster_id, 
    p.post_time, 
    p.post_id,   
    p.topic_id,
    u.user_id, 
    u.username                
FROM posts as p 
INNER JOIN users as u ON u.user_id = p.poster_id 
where p.topic_id = 6 AND (p.poster_id, p.post_time )in(select poster_id, max(post_time) from posts group by poster_id )
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/JTIQbkI5)

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I will test this in the next few minutes. I thought so, that I need a second query but I dont know how...brb.

Comment: @Jens as you already pointed out *Using columns in Select which are not in group by is in most db's forbiden, becuase it is not defined which values are shown* you shouldn't give an answer which will fail with *this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by*. https://dbfiddle.uk/3lZazU49

Comment: @ErgestBasha Thanks for the hint. Have overseen it and changed my answer now

Comment: I tried this query but our SQL was gone because of a loop, so I had to restart the hole server. I would love to spend you guys a coffee or donation via paypal. How is it possible to contact you, to get this sorted?

Comment: @Jens I accpeted your anwser now, because this query works. You forgot just one think in the query and this was the topic_id. Could you please add this before the group by? And then I have another question. Is it possible to count how many group by´s was done inside the query? Maybe something like COUNT(poster_id) as POSTSDONE?

Comment: @labu77 I have done it

Comment: @Jens Thank you. Like a charm ;) - Could you please say something to my last question? Is it possible to count the poster_id entrys in the posts table, before the poster_id gets grouped by? Das wäre wirklich klasse, wenn ich diese Information noch mit anzeigen könnte. Vielen Dank für diese letzte Info Jens.

Comment: @labu77 If you work with CTE than you can do it

Comment: @Jens I see, CTE means Common Table Expression, I dont know how to do this. I just want to use your query. Is it possible to implement a counting in it?

Comment: somthing like `SELECT 
    p.poster_id, 
    p.post_time, 
    p.post_id,   
    p.post_time,
    u.user_id, 
    u.username,
  numberof
FROM posts as p 
INNER JOIN users as u ON u.user_id = p.poster_id 
INNER JOIN (select poster_id, count(*) as numberOf from posts as x group by poster_id)  as y on y.poster_id=p.poster_id
where (p.poster_id, p.post_time )in(select poster_id, max(post_time) from posts group by poster_id ,p.post_time )`

Comment: Awesome Jens, works like a charm. You only missed the topic_id in the inner join. I added it and now I have the number. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is that all your non-aggregated fields must be present inside the `GROUP BY` clause. As long as this condition is not met, you either have an error fired by your DBMS, or expect some subtle output mistakes. Additionally your query would fire a syntax error due to the comma after the last selected field in the `SELECT` clause.

If you're using MySQL 8.0, you can use the [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) window function to select your last post time for each poster (rownum = 1, partitioned by poster, ordered by post_time desc), then join back to your users table to get information.

```
WITH topic_id6 AS (
    SELECT poster_id, post_time, post_id, topic_id,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY topic_id, poster_id ORDER BY post_time DESC) AS rn 
    FROM POSTS
)
SELECT id6.poster_id, id6.post_time, id6.post_id, id6.topic_id, u.*
FROM       topic_id6 id6 
INNER JOIN USERS     u
        ON id6.poster_id = u.user_id
       AND id6.rn = 1
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/7w0mnP4Y).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I use mariaDB. It this also possible?

Comment: Yes, this solution would work in MariaDB too. Make sure to avoid tagging the wrong DBMS in your post.

Comment: Thank you. You used topic_id6 but the forum has many topics, not only topic_id 6. Is it possible to write this different, to match all topics and not only topic_id 6? I know this WHERE topic_id = 6 I can change but in your query the whole names has 6 in it.

Comment: Check the updated query, make sure to point out in your post description that you need this query to be generalized on topic_id values.

Comment: Check also the updated fiddle link.